# How can I access a function in one class from another AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a AS3 MP3 player. The player class is called Mp3PlayerFrontEnd and controls the play and pause buttons. The playlist class is called PlaylistBoxItem and loads the track names into a playlist from XML. On each line of the playlist is a download button. When the download button is pressed, I want the player to pause. I thought I could just _player.pause(); from the playlist class but it doesnt work.

So my question is... How do I access the function in the MP3 player class from the playlist class?

I did not make this, I purchased it. I asked the guy who made it for help and he responded back...

"Normally you will just have to get access to the Mp3Player instance in PlaylistListboxItem class and call pause() on it in download function. I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to create a public static instance of a holder class that could be used access the player from wherever in code."

I do not know how to make a public static instance or where to put it.

Would I need to make a new class?
Where would I import it from?
How would I write the function?
Thanks.
Rich

Comment: do you know anything about actionscript / can you post some code?

Comment: Create a custom event class and dispatch that event when the button is clicked. If the class dispatching the event is a child of the class listening, it will bubble up fine. If it's not, just add a listener to the stage instead. Here's a link with some info on custom event classes: http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2007/10/23/as3/as3-custom-events/

Comment: Yes, I know a bit about Actionscript.  Here's the beginning of the MP3 Player class...public class Mp3PlayerFrontEnd extends MovieClip implements IDisposable
 {
  private var _player:Mp3Player;
  private var _currentTrack:int = 0;
   
  public function Mp3PlayerFrontEnd()
  {
   repeatButton.addEventListener(MultiStateButtonStateEvent.STATE_CHANGED, evthndlRepeatTrack);
   playPauseButton.addEventListener(MultiStateButtonStateEvent.STATE_CHANGED,evthndlPlayPause);
The evthndlPlayPause function calls _player.pause();  I need PlaylistboxItem (not a child) to call _player.pause();

Answer (score 1):

whatever class is in control of everything needs a reference to your player.

So if your play list class is where you want to use play/pause/etc in the constructor add a place for a reference to the mp3player.

```
public class PlayListBoxItem
{
    private var myMp3Player:Mp3Player;

    // the class constructor
    public function PlayListboxItem(myMp3Player:Mp3Player)
    {
        this.myMp3Player = myMp3Player;
    }
}
```

now anywhere in the play list class you can access your mp3 player with myMp3Player.start() .stop(), .whatever public functions are there.

Make sure start and stop are public functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didnt work.  Throws a bunch of errors. Can I email you the whole package?  Send me your email address.  richgags@aol.com.  Thanks.